# How to use ADO.Net Entity Data Model with two tables?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two tables: Student (StuID, Name, Sex, MajorID, ...) and Major (MajorID, MajorName, ...).
I would like to get result: StuID, Name, MajorName.
How to retrieve this record using ADO.Net Entity Data Model?

Comment: For this, I've tried: (from s in Entity.Student join m in Entity.Major on s.MajorID=m.MajorID select s, m.MajorName).ToList();

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are asking for C# LINQ query, if you are not, please ignore my anwser.

```
var result = from s in Student 
             join m in Major on s.MajorID equal m.MajorID
             select new {s.StuID, s.Name, m.MajorName}
```